# How to set content type globally in node.js (express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, content-type

I might be wrong but I wasn't able to find this in any documentation. 
I am trying to set content type globally for any response and did it like:

```
    // Set content type GLOBALLY for any response.
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.contentType('application/json');
    next();
  });
```

before defining my routes.

```
 // Users REST methods.
  app.post('/api/v1/login', auth.willAuthenticateLocal, users.login);
  app.get('/api/v1/logout', auth.isAuthenticated, users.logout);
  app.get('/api/v1/users/:username', auth.isAuthenticated, users.get);
```

For some reason this doesn't work. Do you know what I am doing wrong? Setting it in each method separately, works but I want it globally...

Answer (score 20):

Try [this](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) for Express 4.0 :

```
// this middleware will be executed for every request to the app
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Content-Type",'application/json');
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Found the issue: this setting has to be put BEFORE:

```
app.use(app.router)
```

so the final code is:

```
// Set content type GLOBALLY for any response.
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.contentType('application/json');
  next();
});

// routes should be at the last
app.use(app.router)
```

Comment: Error: 'app.router' is deprecated, Please see the 3.x to 4.x migration guide for details on how to update your app.