# Browser downloads the html file instead of opening

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have created a server with Node.JS express where I open html file in public folder.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(8080);
```

I have done this before without any problems. But in this project when I try to open the server in `127.0.0.1:8080` it automatically downloads the index.html file. I tried it with different browsers but result was same.

---

**UPDATE**
I could open html file in Edge. But it was very very slow like it is processing some thing. And it got stuck when I send a request to the server.

I tried opening the HTML file separately with the browser it works without any problem.

And tried giving another html file location, result was same.

Comment: show full code, ur middleware where page is rendered

Comment: Did you configure a view engine?

Comment: @JonathanNielsen I think know. Actually I don't know what it is.

Comment: @AnmolMittal I am not allowed to show my code.

Comment: Check the content-type header maybe it's not setting correctly, it should look similar to this: `content-type:text/html; `

Comment: @td-lambda I haven't use such an option in my code. Where do I add that?

Comment: That's just what browsers will do when the content type is incorrect.  You should check what the content type is by opening the page in chrome and checking the headers. [Also check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671174/how-to-set-content-type-globally-in-node-js-express)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what is the exact problem here. But I got to know that it has to do something with content type as *td-lambda* mentioned in the comments. So I found a solution like this.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8080);
app.set({
     'Content-Type': 'text/html'
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

And this solved my problem.

Answer (score -2):

It is because your content type was initially `application/js` so it renders as a app.
Convert it into `text` or `html` and it will render correctly.